# Get Django search query right

Tags: django, search, view

Im currently facing a problem since a couple of days for now. I simply want to implement a search view into my Django app. But when i try to search something on my App i get the following error:

**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given__init__() takes

In the end i want that my Query is a combination of category and searchword. So that the user can filter specific categories (Just like Amazon.com searchfield) e.g.: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?category=1&q=hallo`

**base.html**

```
...
   <div class="globalsearch">
            <form id="searchform" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <label for="{{ categorysearch_form.category.id_for_label }}">In category: </label> {{ categorysearch_form.category }}
                <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search for ...">
                <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

...
```

categorysearch_form is a dropdown selector that gets his ID from the Database.

**views.py**

```
...
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
from django.views.generic import ListView


class globalsearch(ListView):
"""
Display a Post List page filtered by the search query.
"""
model = Post
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Post.objects.published()

    keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if keywords:
        query = SearchQuery(keywords)
        title_vector = SearchVector('title', weight='A')
        content_vector = SearchVector('content', weight='B')
        tag_vector = SearchVector('tag', weight='C')
        vectors = title_vector + content_vector + tag_vector
        qs = qs.annotate(search=vectors).filter(search=query)
        qs = qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vectors, query)).order_by('-rank')

    return qs

...
```

**urls.py**

```
...

url(r'^search/$', views.globalsearch.as_view(), name='search'),

...
```

**Search.html** results are getting displayd here:

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Project: https://github.com/rsmvdl/quickblog

Comment: do you know which line exactly the error occurs?

Comment: Nope... If you have any hint where to set the brakpoint. Sry but im new to this

Comment: Can you upload your whole errors that show in runserver?

Comment: please see: https://pastebin.com/WWvNhgts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `globalsearch` is class based view it should be `globalsearch.as_view()` in your urls:

```
url(r'^search/$', views.globalsearch.as_view(), name='search'),
```

Comment: opps it's the right answer. I try to find problems in postgres search

Comment: Seem right but now i have another issue: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'published'

Comment: @Venom this new error comes from this line `qs = Post.objects.published()`. Check you model manager does it have `published` method.

Comment: I guess:

    published_date = EncryptedDateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

Comment: @Venom no, looks like it's your model not model manager. Since it's requered additional information such as your model.py file and not related to current question you'd better to open new question for this problem.